# Login page redirects back only to a naked partialview

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I use jquery ajax to call (get) an action which renders a partialview for creating(inputting) a new product. The content of this partialview is inserted into a vid tag in a full page which has a base _layout. The ajax code below:

```
 $("#Create").on('click', function (e) {
    //debugger;
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",               
        data: { returnUrl: String(window.location) },  <-- passing in the Url
        url: "/CreateGroup/CreateGroup",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#group-list").html(data);
        },
    });
})
.....
<div id="group-list">
    @Html.Partial("PagedGroupList")
</div>
```

The action:

```
// GET: /Create/
[Authorize]
public PartialViewResult CreateGroup(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    CreateGroupModel cgm = new CreateGroupModel();
    cgm.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    cgm.group = new Static_Group();
    return PartialView("CreateGroup", cgm);
}
```

Now if I login first before clicking CREATE button, eveerything is fine as expected. The problem is when CREATE button is clicked without login first. Due to [Authorize], the login page will come first and after login, it is expected to redirect back to my CREATE partialview inside the full page together. The problem is that the login page redirects back to a NAKED create partialview without any of its parent view's elements. If the CREATE page is NOT a partialview, login page redirects back to the full page perfectly.

I use MVC4 defafult login. I tried to make the login page into a ajax form submit and use OnSuccess to call document.location in both the login page and the create partialview, but I found it is an issue of returnUrl of the partialview. I also tried Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri, but it gives the same URL which is "/CreateGroup/CreateGroup?returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dev.com%3A22531%2F" or in full: http://www.dev.com:22531/CreateGroup/CreateGroup?returnUrl=http://www.dev.com:22531/. If you put the Url into a browser, it also displays the pure partialview.

I believe I must have missed something obvious coz this should be a common scenario but I could not find any threads from googling. Is there a URL which displays a partialview inside its parent view together? if not, then possible to redirect back to a previous view from a partialview?

---

Looks there is no URL for a partialview with its host page. The solution I can think of at the moment is get login redirect to the host page and pass in the partialview name in Model or viewbag or session temp to render the whole page again with the right partialview in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I work around this issue. Don't feel very comfortable with it. If anyone has a better solution, please help.

I added two string vars in LoginModel:
            public string RetUrl { get; set; }
            public string UrlReferrer { get; set; }

In get Login action:

```
        public PartialViewResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath;
        LoginModel lgm = new LoginModel();
        lgm.UrlReferrer = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
        lgm.RetUrl = returnUrl;
        return PartialView(lgm);
    }
```

In post Login action:

```
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                model.IsLoggedIn = true;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.RetUrl))
                {
                    model.RetUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home"); 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }
        return PartialView("Login", model);
    }
```

in Login.cshtml: put two hidden fields to retain Model preset value:

```
             @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RetUrl)
             @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UrlReferrer)
```

In ajax OnSuccess event handler, append a CallPartial querystring in the end of returnUrl and redirect to this returnUrl:

```
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
function logInComplete() {
    //debugger;
    if ('@Model.IsLoggedIn' == 'True' && '@Model.UrlReferrer' != '') {
        //debugger;
        var returnUrl = '@Model.UrlReferrer';
        if ('@Model.RetUrl' != '@Model.UrlReferrer') {
            if (returnUrl.indexOf('?') == -1) {
                returnUrl = returnUrl + "?CallPartial=True";
            }
            else {
                returnUrl = returnUrl + "&CallPartial=True";
            }
        }
        document.location = returnUrl;
    } 
}
```

Now back to the CREATE partialview host page:

```
         $('.ifCallPartial').each(function () {
        //debugger;
        if ('@Request["CallPartial"]' == "True") {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                CallCreate();
            });
        }
    });

    function CallCreate() {
        //debugger;
        //e.preventDefault();
        var returl = String(window.location);
        var n = returl.indexOf("?CallPartial");
        if (n >= 1) {
            returl = returl.substring(0, n);
        }
        else {
            n = returl.indexOf("CallPartial");
            if (n >= 1) {
                returl = returl.substring(0, n);
            }
        }
        $.ajax({                
            type: "GET",
            data: { returnUrl: returl },
            url: "/CreateGroup/CreateGroup",
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#group-list").html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    }
```